# How to make @View annotation working using FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using the FOSRestBundle in my RESTful Symfony2 app. I want to serialize the entity by using JMS. Unfortunately the @View annotations doesn't have any effect. They seems be not used at all. But when using $handler->setExclusionStrategyGroups(['details']) it will work fine. How can I make @View() make work properly?

Another thing is that in the cgetAction() I won't see the 'data' json property in my response. Do I understand it correctly that 'data' is the default property for collections?

In my controller I've defined these annotations. It doesn't work.

```
/**
 * @View(serializerGroups={"details"})
 * @View(serializerEnableMaxDepthChecks=true)
 */
public function getAction($id)
{
    return $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('MyFooBundle:Bar')
                ->find($id);
}
```

Directly set the context groups. This works. The JMS context groups has it effect.

```
public function getAction($id)
{
    $bar = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('MyFooBundle:Bar')
                ->find($id);

    $handler = $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler');
    $handler->setExclusionStrategyGroups(['details']);
    $view = $this->view($bar, 200);
    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

No 'data' container property in JSON response.

```
/**
 * @View(serializerGroups={"list"})
 * @View(serializerEnableMaxDepthChecks=true)
 */
public function cgetAction(Request $request, ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
{
    return $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('MyFooBundle:Bar')
                ->findAll();
}
```

Snippet of my Bar entity class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Baz", inversedBy="bar")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="baz_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @JMS\MaxDepth(1)
 * @JMS\Groups({"details"})
*/
private $baz;
```

config.yml snippet:

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    view: { annotations: false }

fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: force
```

Thank you!
Richard

Comment: had any luck with this?

Comment: Nope. I'm not working on it right now. Meanwhile I'm waiting for the solution.

Comment: and why you disabled annotations in sensio_framework_extra ? does it work if you enable it?